# How to emulate click event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have simple code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    url = document.location.href.split('#');

    if(url[1] === 'button-show-modal'){
        console.log('true');
        jQuery('#button-show-modal').click();
    }
)
```

So when page is loaded i see in console true, but no modal appears... If i run `jQuery('#button-show-modal').click();` by myself modal appears as it should so generally `click` event doesn't appear. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You want to trigger the click in jQuery. The code below is assuming you actually have a click event handler in place already on the element.

```
jQuery('#button-show-modal').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Isn't `.click()` just an alias for `.trigger('click')`?

Comment: @Kirix where are you delcaring your click handler? could you post this in your question?

Comment: thanks for answers. Problem was that i triggered click before the default behavior on this click so it just doesn't had anything to show.

Answer (score 1):

I did so:

```
jQuery('#button-show-modal')[0].click();
```

First index in jQuery object is DOM element: [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)